# Libraries in Android Studio - how not to produce a full copy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-import

I am in the process of migrating from Eclipse to Studio.

I have one Eclipse project which is a personal library of various bits and pieces that I use in other projects. I have successfully imported that library project into Studio.

When I import a project that uses that library, the importer seems to copy the whole library project into the app project, source and all.

This, obviously, is not what is required. I've tried many things and wasted a LOT of time trying to overcome this. So...

Q: Within Studio / Gradle, how do I replicate the Eclipse functionality Project / Properties / Android / Add... to just reference the library project and not produce a stand-alone copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify in your `settings.gradle` a relative path using the `project().projectDir` property, something like this:

```
 include ':lib'
 project(':lib').projectDir = new File('xxxxxx') // Relative file path from your settings.gradle
```

In this way you can use the lib module inside a project without cloning the code.

Example:

```
    Project0
    |--library
    |----build.gradle
    |build.gradle
    |settings.gradle

    Project1
    |--app
    |----build.gradle
    |build.gradle
    |settings.gradle
```

in `Project1/settings.gradle`

```
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project0/library')
```

in `Project1/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':library')
}
```

Comment: OK, I have got it working. Thanks for your help.

What I have learned is that the library module is NOT a copy. It seems it is linked into Project1 as a convenience. Any change made to the library withn "Project1" is reflected in the files in "Project0". And vice versa.

It all makes sense, in the rear vision mirror, but is is all very confusing for a newcomer.